# Tensorflow Build from source cannot identify Cudnn.h

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Tensorflow version 2.0 beta

CUDA- 3.0 (Trying to install)

CUDNN -6.5

Operating System- Windows 10

I am trying to build tensorflow 2.0 from source. But it seems the system is 
unable to find cudnn.h file which is there in the file path.

[image: Cannot find cudnn.h in the path]

Below image shows that cudnn.h is indeed available in the specified path.
[image: Proof that cudnn.h is there is there in the folder]

How to resolve this ?

Has someone tried building tensorflow 2.0 with cuda support 3.0 in windows 10. If yes, please help me out.

Comment: is the version in your cudnn.h file indeed 6.5?

Comment: @jeremy_rutman If i remember correctly. Yes

Comment: You can just check within the file, its probably written there

Comment: check this out https://github.com/google/jax/issues/627

Comment: may by try running with  `--action_env CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH="C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.1"`.       https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28865